# Header / Footer for loggedin user vs not loggedin user

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Just checking how to implement this - the different header/footer views between the different user states. on my site i have 4 different header/footer types. one for loggedin users, one for non loggedin users, one for blocked users and one for the error pages.

So the question is: Do i need 4 different php files for each header/footer and use conditional logic based on active page/user session to load the header/footer OR do i only have 1 header/footer file and it can dynamically pull in the content based on active page/session - which in essence means all business logic for these different types will be in 1 file vs 4 files.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of preference, there isn't anything wrong with having 1 header/footer and conditionally displaying your content, isn't really much different than having 4 files, so long as your logic is sound.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to always error on the side of organization so I would seperate each situation out with their own folder and just structure it like so...

```
application
    |
    |...
    |
    |_views
        |
        |_user
        |   |_header.php
        |   |_footer.php
        |
        |_blocked
        |   |_header.php
        |   |_footer.php
        |
        |_error
        |   |_header.php
        |   |_footer.php
        |
        |_public
            |_header.php
            |_footer.php
```

This way you can specify in the view load which header you want via the path

```
$this->load->view('user/header');
```

and it is very obvious to anyone looking at this out of context to tell what you are doing compared to

```
$this->load->view('error/header');
```

And for the logic of knowing which one to load, all of that needs to be determined in the controller.  You should not be making those decisions in your view.